# nodejs JavaScript heap out of memory testing RNG with pracrand

Tags: node.js

I wrote a small seeded RNG and now I'm attempting to run some statistical tests on it using pracrand. The rng is here: https://github.com/nomadcrypto/seededrsa/blob/master/rng.js and the test code is:

```
const RNG = require("./rng");

function test() {
    const seed = "praise you muffin lion enable neck grocery crumble super myself license ghost"
    const rng = new RNG(seed)

    while(true) {
        var bytes = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8)
        rng.nextBytes(bytes)
        process.stdout.write(bytes.toString("binary"))

    }


}

test()
```

I run the test like this:
node /path/to/test_rng.js | /path/to/RNG_test stdin8

This should be outputting 8bit random binary strings to stdout and pracrand is reading them from stdin. This always dies at the same point and shows the following errors

```
RNG_test using PractRand version 0.93
RNG = RNG_stdin8, seed = 0x61ce6e4b
test set = normal, folding = standard (8 bit)

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20190311.183904.23092.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 0x959570 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x95a25e node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb3735e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb37594 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xf36bd2  [node]
 6: 0xf36cd8 v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) [node]
 7: 0xf433f8 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xf43f0b v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xf46c41 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xf10e74 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationSpace) [node]
11: 0x11c72be v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInNewSpace(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x82556f4fc5d 
rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x61ce6e4b
length= 1 megabyte (2^20 bytes), time= 34.0 seconds
  Test Name                         Raw       Processed     Evaluation
  BCFN(2+0,13-7,T)                  R=+39522  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  BCFN(2+1,13-7,T)                  R=+40616  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  BCFN(2+2,13-8,T)                  R=+43491  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  BCFN(2+3,13-8,T)                  R=+32793  p =  2e-8323    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  BCFN(2+4,13-8,T)                  R=+20180  p =  1e-5122    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  BCFN(2+5,13-9,T)                  R=+12114  p =  4e-2723    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  BCFN(2+6,13-9,T)                  R= +5993  p =  7e-1348    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  DC6-9x1Bytes-1                    R= +6430  p =  8e-3715    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  Gap-16:A                          R=+19027  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  Gap-16:B                          R=+80036  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:(0,14-4)              R=+23224  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:(1,14-5)              R=+26476  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:(2,14-5)              R= +3407  p =  2e-2824    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:(3,14-6)              R= +2417  p =  6e-1850    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:(4,14-7)              R= +1720  p =  1e-1368    FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:(5,14-8)              R= +1161  p =  2.8e-835   FAIL !!!!!!!   
  FPF-14+6/16:(6,14-8)              R=+527.7  p =  9.0e-380   FAIL !!!!!!!   
  FPF-14+6/16:(7,14-9)              R=+758.3  p =  9.9e-478   FAIL !!!!!!!   
  FPF-14+6/16:(8,14-10)             R=+545.9  p =  5.5e-291   FAIL !!!!!!    
  FPF-14+6/16:(9,14-11)             R=+670.1  p =  6.4e-293   FAIL !!!!!!    
  FPF-14+6/16:all                   R=+29837  p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:all2                  R=+306094057 p = 0           FAIL !!!!!!!!  
  FPF-14+6/16:cross                 R= +6279  p =  2e-4805    FAIL !!!!!!!!
  ...and 22 test result(s) without anomalies
```

This is pretty heavy I'm sure. Can anyone provide some tips or tricks that can help me properly test this rng?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the stream api and to just push a buffer instead of printing a binary string

```
const RNG = require("./rng");

var crypto= require("crypto");
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

var Readable = stream.Readable;

function RandomStream(options) {
  if (!(this instanceof RandomStream)) {
    return new RandomStream(options);
  }
  Readable.call(this, options);

  this.seed = "praise you muffin lion enable neck grocery crumble super myself license ghost"
  this.rng = new RNG(this.seed)
  this.bytes = Buffer.allocUnsafe(8);

}
util.inherits(RandomStream, Readable);

RandomStream.prototype._read = function (size) {
  var ready = true;
  while (ready) { 
    var bytes = this.rng.randomBytes(8)
    //bytes = crypto.randomBytes(8)
    ready = this.push(bytes)
  }

};

var readstream = new RandomStream();
readstream.pipe(process.stdout)
```

This works as expected with both my rng's randomBytes and crypto.randomBytes. So far nothing found in practrand

```
(env) nomadcrypto@nomadcrypto:~/projects/seededrsa$ node test_rng.js |/home/nomadcrypto/projects/practrand/build/RNG_test stdin8
RNG_test using PractRand version 0.93
RNG = RNG_stdin8, seed = 0x3bb19275
test set = normal, folding = standard (8 bit)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 4 megabytes (2^22 bytes), time= 2.3 seconds
  no anomalies in 56 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 8 megabytes (2^23 bytes), time= 5.0 seconds
  no anomalies in 60 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 16 megabytes (2^24 bytes), time= 9.9 seconds
  no anomalies in 66 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 32 megabytes (2^25 bytes), time= 19.1 seconds
  no anomalies in 72 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 64 megabytes (2^26 bytes), time= 38.2 seconds
  no anomalies in 76 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 128 megabytes (2^27 bytes), time= 76.0 seconds
  no anomalies in 82 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 256 megabytes (2^28 bytes), time= 147 seconds
  no anomalies in 88 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 512 megabytes (2^29 bytes), time= 289 seconds
  no anomalies in 92 test result(s)

rng=RNG_stdin8, seed=0x3bb19275
length= 1 gigabyte (2^30 bytes), time= 571 seconds
  no anomalies in 98 test result(s)
```